# Dupehammer "marked as duplicate by" shows only the gold-badge user, removing previous voters

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Using the new Dupehammer (name subject to change?), I closed a question which was on the Close Votes review queue: [How can I call my c# functions from an external js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620857/how-can-i-call-my-c-sharp-functions-from-an-external-js-file)

The question **already had two close votes** and I've added mine as the third.
The close message says:

> marked as duplicate by Kobi 5 mins ago

I think it should specify all users who voted:

> marked as duplicate by Jane, Jack, Kobi 5 mins ago

This is the case for moderators, for example [CSS "::" meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720519/css-meaning) :

> marked as duplicate by Jukka K. Korpela, BoltClock♦ Feb 6 '13 at 7:26

I think it looks better when more than a single user closes a question. It is also important to give credit to the person who found the duplicate, and other people who voted.

Comment: Given [Is the ability to unilaterally close/reopen duplicates for Gold Badge holders SO specific?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231540/is-the-ability-to-unilaterally-close-reopen-duplicates-for-gold-badge-holders-so) is closed as a dup using the Shadow Wizard's Duplicate Hammer and it shows 1 other name, it seems to be working in some cases.  Do you know if the 2 existing close votes were duplicate close votes, or for some other reason?

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Interesting! I'm sure there where two close votes for the same duplicate - I picked the duplicate from the list and it shows `2` with a blue background. Maybe these were flags, and not close votes? Hmm... Now I'm embarrassed and confused.

Comment: OK, I tried again, and it does show all users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629026/boolean-variable-to-identify-prime-number .

Comment: Ok, so they might have been flags, or they might have been close votes of a different type.  If it is the former, then there is no issue, but if it is the latter, then the behavior is definitely inconsistent with how the mod-hammer works.

Comment: Closing my own question as "can no longer be reproduced" ☹