# Is the ability to unilaterally close/reopen duplicates for Gold Badge holders SO specific?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, moderator-abilities, dupehammer

This is posted and answered on SO meta: [When did I get close-vote superpowers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers?cb=1)

Does that mean the ability to unilaterally close/reopen duplicates for Gold Badge holders **SO specific**? Or does it work across all SE sites?

Comment: It works across all SE sites.

Comment: I just proved this is not SO specific by casting a binding vote, having a golden [support tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/support?userid=152859). :)