# Why a gold badge isn't shown near a user name in this question?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

[Is the ability to unilaterally close/reopen duplicates for Gold Badge holders SO specific?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231540/is-the-ability-to-unilaterally-close-reopen-duplicates-for-gold-badge-holders-so)

In this question, Shadow Wizard doesn't have gold badge shown near his name, however he closed this question, having gold support badge and [still has it since April 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/support?userid=152859).

> [image]

Is it a bug or I am missing something?